# Select and Inner Join Returning Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, inner-join

I'm developing a query to print a report about user travel. However, this query is returning 4 rows instead of two. Explaining the business rule: A user creates a travel solicitation and adds different destinations as a route. The user must define the percentage that each subsidiary of the route must pay for the travel. The trip can have multiple destinations or just one. When I execute the following query:

```
Select Distinct sv.Description,
    st.Description,
    us.Code, us.Name,
    rt.Destination, rt.Description, rt.BeginDate, rt.FInishDate,
    rat.Percentage,
    fl.Code, fl.Name
FROM TravelSolicitation sv
INNER JOIN Situation st ON sv.IdSituation = st.Id
INNER JOIN Duser us ON sv.IdUser = us.Id
INNER JOIN Itinerary rt ON rt.IdSolicitation = sv.Id
INNER JOIN Apportionment rat ON rat.IdSolicitation = sv.Id
INNER JOIN Subsidiary fl ON rat.IdSubsidiary = fl.Id
WHERE sv.Id = 1
```

I get the following result:

[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE4J8.png)

**My Problem:**
Considering the Apportionment table the query result should show only 2 lines since the Apportionment for each subsidiary is 80 and 20. If I use 3 different apportionment (i.e. 50,30,20) for 3 subsidiaries the query result will show 9 lines. I've tried to use LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and OUTER JOIN too but it doesn't work.

How can I develop this query to return only the 2 lines?

**My Expected output:**

```
+----------+-------------+-----+------+------------+------+-----------+------------+------+---+------------+
| Travel 1 | Credit Test | 110 | Paul | Ny         | Work | BeginDate | FinishDate | 20.0 | 4 | City B Sub |
+----------+-------------+-----+------+------------+------+-----------+------------+------+---+------------+
| Travel 1 | Credit Test | 110 | Paul | Washington | Fun  | BeginDate | FinishDate | 80.0 | 2 | City A Sub |
+----------+-------------+-----+------+------------+------+-----------+------------+------+---+------------+
```

*Note: I notice that the Apportionment INNER JOIN generates the 4 lines. The other INNER JOINS apparently work. I'm using SQL Server*

The **MVCE** to reproduce my problem:

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Subsidiary] (
    [Id] bigint NOT NULL,
    [Code] varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Subsidiary_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

CREATE TABLE [Apportionment] (
    [Id] bigint NOT NULL,
    [IdSubsidiary] bigint NOT NULL,
    [IdSolicitation] bigint NOT NULL,
    [Percentage] decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Apportionment_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

CREATE TABLE [Itinerary] (
   [Id] bigint NOT NULL,
   [IdSolicitation] bigint NOT NULL,
   [Destination] varchar(200) NULL,
   [Description] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   [BeginDate] datetime NOT NULL,   
   [FInishDate] datetime NULL,
   [MultipleItinerary] bit NOT NULL,
   
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Itinerary_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   (
     [Id] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [Situation](
    [Id] bigint NOT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    [Description] varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    [ValidateDate] smallint NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Situation_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [TravelSolicitation] 
    ([Id] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [IdSituation] bigint NOT NULL, 
    [IdUser] bigint NOT NULL, 
    [Description] varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
    [GoDate] datetime NOT NULL, 
    [BackDate] datetime NOT NULL, 

CONSTRAINT [PK_TravelSolicitation_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   (
     [Id] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [Duser] (
    [Id] bigint NOT NULL,
    [Code] varchar(10),
    [Name] varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Duser_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

**Foreign Keys:**

```
ALTER TABLE Apportionment
ADD FOREIGN KEY (IdSubsidiary) REFERENCES Subsidiary(Id); 

ALTER TABLE Apportionment
ADD FOREIGN KEY (IdSolicitation) REFERENCES TravelSolicitation(Id); 

ALTER TABLE Itinerary
ADD FOREIGN KEY (IdSolicitation) REFERENCES TravelSolicitation(Id); 

ALTER TABLE TravelSolicitation
ADD FOREIGN KEY (IdSituation) REFERENCES Situation(Id); 

ALTER TABLE TravelSolicitation
ADD FOREIGN KEY (IdUser) REFERENCES Duser(Id);
```

**Inserts**

```
INSERT INTO Duser (Id,Code,Name) VALUES (1,110,'Paul')

INSERT INTO Situation (Id,Name,Description,ValidateDate) VALUES (1,'Situation A','Credit Test',1)

INSERT INTO Subsidiary (Id,Code,Name) VALUES (1,'2','City A Sub');
INSERT INTO Subsidiary (Id,Code,Name) VALUES (2,'4','City B Sub');

INSERT INTO TravelSolicitation(IdSituation,IdUser,Description,GoDate,BackDate) VALUES (1,1,'Travel 1','20-10-2021','20-11-2021');

INSERT INTO Itinerary (Id,IdSolicitation,Destination,Description,BeginDate,FInishDate,MultipleItinerary) VALUES (1,1,'Washington','Fun','20-10-2021','10-11-2021',1)
INSERT INTO Itinerary (Id,IdSolicitation,Destination,Description,BeginDate,FInishDate,MultipleItinerary) VALUES (2,1,'NY','Work','10-11-2021','20-11-2021',1)

INSERT INTO Apportionment(Id,IdSubsidiary,IdSolicitation,Percentage) VALUES (1,1,1,80.0)
INSERT INTO Apportionment(Id,IdSubsidiary,IdSolicitation,Percentage) VALUES (2,2,1,20.0)
```

Comment: I edited the question to mention the tool I used to build the application.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is anyway a code smell: you need to think about what your joins do, and whether any of them should be semi-joins (such as `EXISTS` or `IN`) and whether any should be pre-aggregated joins or "top 1 per group" joins. There are multiple `Subsidiary` for every `Apportionment` and multiple `TravelSolicitation`, so you need to think carefully about what result you actually want. Blindly throwing `DISTINCT` at a query in the hope that duplicate rows will go away is not the solution

Comment: @Charlieface I really don't understand why Inner Join `Apportionment` is joining the two Apportionment with different `subsidiary` since each 'IdSubsidiary' is different on `Apportionment`.

Comment: @DaleK column `status`?

Comment: You have two `Itinerary` and two `Subsidiary`. 2*2=4. Again: think about what the joins do: you have one `TravelSolicitation`, foreign-keyed (by definition) to a single `Situation` and a single `Duser`. There can be multiple `Itinerary` (by definition for every `TravelSolicitation`, multiple `Apportionment` and multiple `Subsidiary`, so your result is entirely expected. Each join to a one-to-many or many-to-many foreign key is capable of multiplying your rows

Comment: @DaleK sorry, I deleted this column manually. I've updated the create table method.

Comment: Chop code to the first (logically evaluated) subexpression that doesn't return what you expect & give a [mre] including what you expect instead  & why with justification per authoritative documentation. (Absolute basic debugging & question asking.) Then always before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @Charlieface is there a way for me to debug this in SQL server? Inner Join should return records that have corresponding values ​​in both tables, right? So why is returning different values since i'm filtering by Id on `rat.IdSolicitation = sv.Id`

Comment: @OdiumPura if you get the dbfiddle working which I linked we can use that to debug

Comment: @DaleK is this a region problem? In my SQL Server the code works perfectly.

Comment: @OdiumPura yes... as I explained "you are using a ambiguous date format" - you should always use a non-ambiguous format for exactly this reason. (Sorry I non-ambiguous earlier when I mean ambiguous). Such a format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: That join seems to be working perfectly: you have two rows in `Apportionment (IdSubsidiary, IdSolicitation)` with values `(1, 1), (2, 1)` so both are joining to `sv.Id = 1` hence multiplying the rows by two. I'll say it again: read through the values that you have, and think about what each join does

Comment: @DaleK No problem, I updated your link.

Comment: Here...[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35e69c5d44f8bc277dcfb23184199707) @DaleK

Comment: The problem appears to be your `Apportionment` table... it only links to an `Solicitation` record, so with 2 `Apportionment` rows and 2 `Itinerary` rows all linked to only a `Solicitation` record, you naturally get 4 rows resulting. I *think* your `Apportionment` table should link to an `Itinerary` record or so, although I don't quite understand its purpose.

Comment: @DaleK It's linked with two another tables. I've abstracted the solution. I'll try to fix using the other tables.

Comment: @OdiumPura you can't afford to oversimplify the solution else we're not seeing the real problem.

Comment: @Charlieface I think `IN´ may solve my problem.

Comment: @DaleK It a huge DB, but I think the other tables won't help to solve the problem.

Comment: You could try showing is your desired results (as formatted text) for the data provided. Because as you can see each row is unique, so you need to explain what you would hope to see.

Comment: so what two lines you want to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `and rt.id = rat.id` on `INNER JOIN Apportionment rat ON rat.IdSolicitation = sv.Id`.

Since you never use `rt.id` for filtering, it causes your result returning 4 lines.

```
Select Distinct sv.Description,
st.Description,
us.Code, us.Name,
rt.Destination, rt.Description, rt.BeginDate, rt.FInishDate,
rat.Percentage,
fl.Code, fl.Name
FROM TravelSolicitation sv
INNER JOIN Situation st ON sv.IdSituation = st.Id
INNER JOIN Duser us ON sv.IdUser=us.Id
INNER JOIN Itinerary rt ON rt.IdSolicitation = sv.Id 
INNER JOIN Apportionment rat ON rat.IdSolicitation = sv.Id and rt.id = rat.id
INNER JOIN Subsidiary fl ON rat.IdSubsidiary=fl.Id
WHERE sv.Id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt think this way. I was trying tu use `In` like @Charlieface said.